# How to make Spark to fail fast with clarity

Tags: apache-spark

I'm learning Spark, and quite often I have some issue that causes tasks and stages to fail.  With my default configuration, there are rounds of retries and a bunch of ERROR messages to that effect.

While I totally appreciate the idea of retrying tasks when I finally get to production, I'd love to know how to make my application fail at the first sign of trouble so that I can avoid all the extra noise in the logs and within the application history itself.  For example, if I run it out of memory, I'd love to just see the OOM exception near the end of my log and have the whole app fail.

What's the best way to setup configs for this kind of workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `spark.task.maxFailures` to 1.

`spark.task.maxFailures` is the number of individual task failures before giving up on the job, and its default value is 4.